# How to ignore other channels?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to fetch messages from specific channels and sometimes it fetches other channels, I am basically prioritize that it only chooses this specific channel.

Code

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #Ignore messages that aren't sent in 0000000000
    if message.channel.id == 0000000000:
        return

    #Ignore messages sent by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

Basically want to make sure it only fetches this channel and if the ID does match, it will only fetch within that channel!

Comment: why is there an `else` instead of a return in the first ignore, it should be `if message.channel.id != 0000000000: return`

Comment: That was a typo! And it ignores the channel.

Comment: still the code doesn't match the comments, fix one of these, I guess the comments are correct, therefore, `message.channel.id ==` should be `message.channel.id !=`

Comment: Yeah I understand that the comments does not match the code I added them to make it easier to understand what I am doing and I mixed some of the comments up. However, your code worked I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #Ignore messages that aren't sent in 0000000000
    if message.channel.id == 0000000000:
        #bot do what you want just in 0000 channel example:
        await message.delete() #delete every message which is sent in 0000 channel.

    if message.channel.id != 111111111:
        #ignores only 111111 channel, ( thats mean if message is not in 1111)
        return

    #Ignore messages sent by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```